# Function body causing `Abort: Trap 6 error code`

Tags: swift

All I know is that when I uncomment this function body:

```
static func removeFilter(by id: UUID, from ticket: Ticket, using context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
    let first = ticket.filterArray.first { filter in
        filter.uniqueID == id
    }

    guard let first = first else { return }
    context.delete(first)
    try? context.save()
}
```

I get that error.. and the code will not compile.. I wish I could give more context but this is a really vague error message..

`filterArray` is `[CustomType]`

```
CustomType {
    let size: String
    let uniqueID: UUID
}
```

`CustomType` is a managedObjectContext of CoreData

(Will add more code if deemed relevant)

Comment: "CustomType is a managedObjectContext"? Really? Really?

Comment: Anyway, the compiler crashing is Apple's bug and you should report it to them. There's nothing we can do about it here.